# C# OleDb dataGridView fill with textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb

(Sorry for my bad english) I made this program for my dad, so please help me.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Csaba\\Desktop\\Teszt.accdb ;";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        Sql = "select * from 2017";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
            oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] rowS = { NumeleO, AdresaO, NrMatricolO, VJO, NrMO, DataO, TaurO, CodS, };


   int row = 0;
        row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new Object[] { NumeleTxT.Text, AdresaTxT, NrMatricolTxT, VJTxT, NrMTxT, DataTxT, TaurTxt, CodTxT });
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

> Error: 
>       System.InvalidOperationException occurred

```
  HResult=0x80131509
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
   at Apu_Proba_3.Form1.button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Csaba\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Apu Proba 3\Apu Proba 3\Form1.cs:line 79
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 at Apu_Proba_3.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Csaba\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Apu Proba 3\Apu Proba 3\Program.cs:line 19
```

I don't know what's the problem. Please help. I will answer all your questions.

Comment: Before making the program for your dad, you should learn C# for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For InvalidOperationExceptions, it is best to always [check the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) of the method (`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)`) throwing the exception to see what cases the exception is thrown.

Since you are adding values manually, I would first check to see whether you are violating this case first:

> The row returned by the DataGridView.RowTemplate property has more
>   cells than there are columns in the control.

And the check whether you're violating this case:

> The DataGridView has no columns.

If it is neither of these cases, go through the remaining exception cases to see if you are violating them.